# Apple's iOS 14 Translate app on macOS?

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur

In iOS 14, Apple added a Translate app. You're also supposed to be able to run iOS apps on macOS now, but I don't see it in the App Store from my Mac.

Anyone know if it's possible to run it on macOS (version 11, Big Sur).

[image]

Comment: Not sure if Apple will make a native Mac Translate app, but note that if you have an Intel Mac, no iOS apps will work even if you're running Big Sur. iOS apps will only be available on the new Apple Silicon Macs.

Answer (score 2):

macOS Monterey adds the system-wide translation functionality from iOS, but not the separate app.

> #### Translate
>
> **Systemwide Translation**
> Translate text by Control-clicking it and selecting Translate. Then copy the result, change the language, or replace the selected text with the translation. Using Live Text, you can translate selected text in photos.

https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey/features/

Unfortunately [language coverage](https://www.apple.com/macos/feature-availability/#translate-system-wide-translation) is still very limited compared to Google Translate, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This application is not available on macOS at this time